# pymssql can connect but does not return any results

Tags: python, freetds, pymssql

I am connecting to an MS SQL server with pymssql. I can connect by `tsql -H ip -p 1433 -U xx - p xx` and by jupyter notebook. The connection does not return any errors.

However, I tried many queries with pymssql but none of them returned results.

For example, `cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ')`

What should I check now?

Comment: execute query just executes the query
you need to fetch records to display them. Please check for cursor.fetchone :)

Comment: @RanjanaGhimire `cursor.fetchone` returns the database info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the "Iterating through results" section of the [pymssql examples](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/pymssql_examples.html), you can simply iterate through the rows of the result set like this:

```python
crsr = conn.cursor()
crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES")
for row in crsr:
    print(row)
```

Or, to use a more standard DB-API approach:

```python
crsr = conn.cursor()
crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES")
for row in crsr.fetchall():
    print(row)
```